# How to change the behavior of Meteor accounts-ui so when a user logs in, the log out form automatically appears and vice versa

Tags: meteor, reactjs

When a user logs in, I've tried adding a class to the 'logout form' that has a 'display: block' even with the '!important' tag which would override any display property on the logout form. I've tried reloading the page because that does bring up the logout form once a user logs in but it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class AccountsUI extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    Accounts._loginButtonsSession.set('dropdownVisible', true);
    this.view = Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons,
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.container));

       setTimeout(function () {
         window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
           var node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode();
           if (node !== undefined){
            Accounts.onLogin(function(user){
              document.getElementById('login-dropdown-list').className = "accounts-dialog hide-div"
              console.log(document.getElementById('login-dropdown-list').className)
            })
           }
         });
       }, 250)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Blaze.remove(this.view);
  }

  render() {
    return <span ref="container" />
  }
}
```

I'm also going to change how the class additions are triggered. I know that waiting 1/4 a second is very primitive and won't always work.

Answer (score 0):

The `Meteor.userId()` function is reactive, which means if you call it in `getMeteorData()` it will be called again each time the `userId` changes. Save it to `this.data`, and use it in `render()`.

I'd also suggest you create a React wrapper called `LogoutUIWrapper` for the Blaze component that only does wrapping and nothing else, just to make your life easier. See here: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/adding-user-accounts

So you'll need to do something like this:

```
export default class AccountsUI extends React.Component {
  getMeteorData() {
    return {
      userId: Meteor.userId(),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.data.userId ? null : <LogoutUIWrapper /> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This way the `LogoutUIWrapper` component will only appear when the user is logged in.